# What was it like to create a Clojure project before Leiningen?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

I am doing some research for an article and want to mention the problem that Leiningen is trying to solve. I don't know what it was like to create project before Lein but I can only assume one had to create it for the JVM using the `javac` command somewhere to compile it somehow.

So far I have the following - which I am not sure is understood clearly and I want to add more information to the problem. Any ideas?

**Problem:** Creating a project is a lengthy process.

**Solution:** Create and interact with a project using one line commands in the console.

Comment: I'd check out github and search for early clj project.  After all the earliest adopter of clojure (clojure itself) does not use lein.  The deps are in repos and writing plugins for other build tools is no black magic.  So whatever the pain points where back then, some other tool would be the goto nowadays.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to give that a go.

Comment: Quick research lead me to the fact that leiningen is not much younger than clojure itself: leiningen v0.5 was released somewhere around clojure 1.0 release. I guess, like in many other modern languages (almost all of them in fact, from nodejs to rust), it has never been intended to build clojure apps without the proper build/dependency tooling. So, the best illustration for your case could be to show some old school java project setup, from the pre-maven era, and compare it with some relatively modern gradle setup. That should be enough to outline the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the history of a programming language and not about how to actually do something.

Comment: Also back in the days it would have been very easy to get going with clojure since for a standalone project you would just have to gather the deps, put them in lib dir, start `java -cp lib/\* clojure.main -m my.ns` and be going. You can also start a repl with that and develop from there.

Comment: Maybe no suited for SO, but I would be interested to know more.